# MVC Entity separation best practise

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

This is a hypothetical question, lets say i have a very basic forum

I have the following entities (objects)

```
public class User 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public string Username { get; set;}
}

public class Thread
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public Guid Owner { get; set;}//UserId
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ThreadId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public Guid PostedBy { get; set; }//UserId
}
```

I have the following controllers

1. UsersController
2. ThreadsController
3. PostsController

When i want to retrieve a particular thread, or a list of threads, i hit the ThreadsController.

When i want to retrieve posts for a particular thread, i hit the PostsController

**The question:**

If i want to retrieve a list of threads, that a user has created, which of the following would be the best approach:

1. Create a new controller - UserThreadsController, which returns a list of Thread objects
2. Create an additional action method on the ThreadsController, i.e GetByUser
3. Create an additional action method on the UserController, i.e GetThreads

Thanks

Comment: can you post your models?  Does `Threads`  have a foreign key property that links up to the `ID` field of the `User` table?

Comment: The question is not how do i go about retrieving the data, this i am completely comfortable with. The question is how do i structure my controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely going to be closed as opinionated, since, well, it is. My personal opinion is that you have a bit too much separation already.

There needn't be a 1-1 correlation between entities and controllers. In fact, it's generally better to keep controllers a bit more high-level than that, encapsulating concepts, not just one single thing. For example, you could have merely a `ForumController`, with actions to list all threads, and to show a single thread. At least in every forum I've come across, individual posts are never displayed just by themselves, so you don't even need actions for those.

Showing threads specific to a user is a bit of a tossup. It makes sense to have something like this on a `UserController`, but it also makes sense to have all forum-related things in a `ForumController`. I think you could reasonably go either way.

Comment: Thanks for your input Chris. Much appreciated. It does contradict some other advise (or rather an another opinion) i received which was to have have many controllers with few actions, as opposed to few controllers with many actions. Would you give the same opinion if it were a REST service instead of an ASP.Net MVC application? Thanks again

Comment: It depends. In MVC, the pattern, the saying goes "skinny controllers, fat models". However, in MVC, the framework, there's no true Model, and controllers tend to need to do a little more heavy lifting than in a framework that more strictly adheres to the MVC pattern. I'm not necessarily advocating for controllers with thousands of lines of code, but we're really not talking about that here. Even a full basic forum would probably only encompass 6-8 actions, and you can factor out most of the real code for those actions into utility classes.

Comment: Interesting. It makes sense seeing as most of my controller actions are a one liner wrapped in a try catch anyway (the one liner going to a service to handler the heavy lifting). Last question i promise - So to follow a typical REST convention (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) would you say the opposite was true? I know WebApi and Asp.Net MVC are similar in architecture (MVC), but it's convention that's throwing me off now. Thanks again for your input

Comment: Web Api is a bit different as you're setting up a very specific structure for the purposes of the REST API. However, related objects could be handled in the same Web Api controller. For example, with an endpoint like, `PUT /user/1/address/`, I would expect the action to be in something like `UserApiController`, not `AddressApiController`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Much appreciated